# Name is already used or reserved by Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I created a rails application with the following command:

```
rails new Education
```

Now, I am trying to create a new model in rails with the following command:

```
rails generate model Education name:string
```

When running it it returns the following error:

> The name 'Education' is either already used in your application or
>   reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this
>   generator again.

Since I just created a new app and only have one other model and I have a hard time thinking about any reason why Rails would reserve a name like that?

Any thoughts on where this error comes from and how I can work around it?

(I have tried changing the name to something else and it works as expected. Since the name really fits its purpose I don't want to change its name unless there is no other way!)

I am using Ruby 2.0.0 with Rails 4.0.0 and PostgreSQL

Comment: did you call your application Education as well? i.e. `rails new Education`

Comment: Yes. You think that is why?

Comment: that is precisely why

Comment: Ok, thx. Care to make a proper answer I can accept?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You may not create a model with the same name as the Application because it will create conflicting names. When you create an application i.e. `rails new Education` it will create a module named `Education` as follows

```
module Education
  class Application < Rails::Application
  #....
  end
end
```

This named module is then called in files such as `config.ru`, `routes.rb` and `environment.rb` and many more. So if you were able to create a model class by the same name it would create ambiguity as to whether you were calling the Model or the Module.

Answer (score 2):

Adding two other possible reasons people might get this error.

Firstly you've been changing names and the old name is still around as it's a caching issue.

Secondly, it could be a naming conflict with a gem you have installed. So the gem is already using the name you want to use.

**CASE I:: Cache issue**

I got below error::

**`The name 'Activityflow' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.`**

While running **rails g** if you see below messages in initial lines. It could be cache issue:

```
warning: previous definition of CALLBACK_CAMPAIGN_NAME was here
Running via Spring preloader in process 98806
      invoke  active_record
```

Solution is kill spring and it will freeup cache.

Find process id of spring

```
$ ps -ef | grep spring
501 82388 82384   0  2:21PM ??        66:34.87 spring app    | insurance | started 16 hours ago | development mode      
501 82384     1   0  2:21PM ttys005    0:00.84 spring server | insurance | started 16 hours ago
```

Kill process Eg: 82384 in above case

```
$ kill -9 82384
```

Then when you run **rails g** command again; Spring will run/start with fresh contents and model creation succeed.

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 99237
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20200518021818_create_activityflows.rb
  create    app/models/activityflow.rb
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/models/activityflow_spec.rb
```

**CASE II:: Module Issue**

I got below error::

**`The name 'Workflow' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.`**

The issue was I was using gem **gem 'workflow', '~> 2.0.2'** which creates modules names Workflow and does not allow to generate model named Workflow.

> So, be careful when you use any gem and is module name in any gem gets
>   matched with model name.

```
Simple way to check if module name exist is::
$ bin/rails c
[4] pry(main)> Workflow
=> Workflow
[5] pry(main)> Workflow.class
=> Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it's helpful to someone else, I made a silly error and accidentally ran similar lines of code twice (they both created an 'Appointments' scaffold. It wasn't as simple as below, but I was copy/pasting something along these lines (first line succeeded but the second caused the error for obvious reasons).

```
rails g scaffold Appointment user:references viewer:references start_time:datetime end_time:datetime
rails g scaffold Appointment user:references viewer:references start_time:datetime end_time:datetime
```

Note: The error can be (again, obviously) caused by using one of rails's reserved words. An easy way to check for reserved words is https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words